# Is mixins calling super() anti-pattern?

Tags: python, mixins

This maybe Python specific but I presume can be applied to other languages.

To my understanding (I might be very wrong) Mixins are for composition purpose, so that each Mixin should not depend on other Mixins. (except Mixins that inherit other Mixins, that is different story). The idea is that it doesn't matter which order of the inheritance you place them.

Eg.

```
class Device(object):
    def turn_on(self):
      # some code here...

class AdditionMixin(object):
    def add(self, val):
        return self.val + val

class SubtractionMixin(object):
    def minus(self, val):
        return self.val - val

class Calculator(Device, AdditionMixin, SubtractionMixin):
    pass

# or 

class Calculator(Device, SubtractionMixin, AdditionMixin):
    pass

# or

class Calculator(SubtractionMixin, Device, AdditionMixin):
    pass
```

But if Mixins has super() calls, then the MRO start to matter, eg:

```
class AutoTurnOffMixin(object):
    def turn_on(self):
        super(AutoTurnOffMixin, self).turn_on()
        ...
        # set timer and turn off after x seconds 

# AutoTurnOffMixin needs to be in front of Device
class Calculator(AutoTurnOffMixin, Device, ...)
```

And in this case it seems to me that `AutoTurnOffMixin` shouldn't be mixin at all but become a concrete class that extends `Device`, eg `AutoTurnOffDevice`.

I am seeking advice from other Python dev what the best practise here for creating Mixins?

Comment: You make an effective argument that the class shouldn't be a mixin, but that's different from an argument that mixins shouldn't call super() -- unless what you intend to be asserting is that needing to call super() is a code smell that something shouldn't be implemented as a mixin at all. I'm not sure that asking whether others agree with that assertion is a concrete enough question to be answerable here; methods-and-practices questions are generally more welcome on [programmers.se].

Comment: See [Choosing between Stack Overflow and Software Engineering](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/254571/14122); "methods and practices", "architecture and design" are explicitly topical on SE, whereas they're on fuzzier ground here.